# Need immediate help for site for http site loading as https:

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, http, https, webserver

Recently my website, which so far is not secure "just http:" fails with multiple problems when it is wrongly linked as https:, which it is not. Unfortunately That will happen regardless of what I want, whenever sites are linked in google, facebook, or just about anywhere now. In the past I successfully solved this problem by adding this JavaScript near the top of my pages...

```
<script>
// redirect if wrongly linked via https.
if(window.location.href.indexOf("https") >= 0) {
  var loc = window.location.href;
  var newloc = loc.replace("https:","http:"); 
  window.location = newloc;
  }
</script>
```

Well that no longer works. Is seems that all browsers now have the following behavior: If you link a site vai https://, any attempts to load it via http://, even explicitly typing that on the browser URL line, will fail. the browser will continually change it to https:. So what does this to to my page? It causes it to endlessly reload. Obviously i can remove the script above, but then I may as well shut down the site, because almost nothing will work correctly. No cookies, no graphics, nothing works right. Not even the page icons.

So I also tried the reverse of a `.htaccess` file solution, usually used to force https. My version looks like this...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exampledomain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Obviously 'exampledomain' is my domain. I don't know if its doing anything unexpected, but it certainly is not helping.

So what can I do? i realize the long term solution is to become https. That suggestion doesn't help right now. It is a legacy website with over 100 pages. And the way things stand right now, once anyone goes there from an incorrect https: link, they will never get to see any of it. Is there anything i can do for now?

**EDIT...**

Is it possible the server is forcing this on me? I found this article, and have asked my hosting support if anything can be done. If not, it would seem that the hosting company sold me web space, and then made it impossible for people to visit, if I don't upgrade. Is there any test i can do to see if this policy is being enforced by my hosting company?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

**EDIT:** I finally got my site back online. I'm not "answering" my own question, because I strongly suspect even now my answer is incomplete. But two things were done:

1. In my main (document root level), the tech support added these lines. While the lower 3 are similar to something I'd tried (and one of you suggested), without that top line (apparently blocking HSTS), an infinite loop was being generated, when a browser was insisting on https.

   ```
   Header always unset Strict-Transport-Security
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
   RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   ```
2. But why were **MY** browsers "insisting" on HTTPS? Tech support had already verified for themselves that a loop condition of infinite redirects was no longer happening, but I still could not reach my pages from home, in either my firefox or chrome browsers, on either my older or newer machine. But oddly, IE and Edge did work, which led me to realize the difference... I don't use those browsers often (except to check compatibility), so the difference was this: Despite suggestions of clearing cache and cookies, apparently none of those options really flush the history. And if an HTTPS was in recent history, the browsers seem to automatically revert to that one. For that i found the answers (at least for those browsers) in the article below. Once history was truly cleared, there was no longer a problem.

https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/

I suspect I haven't seen the last of this problem, and yes... eventually i WILL make the jump to HTTPS.  I just don't like needing to do so under forced pressure, because of an internal server policy that changed.

Comment: What is the purpose of switching from "https" to "http" ?
Even if you don't have a SSL certificate, https should works anyway

Comment: Can whoever is thinking of down voting please show a measure of kindness? I may not know everything about changing to secure https, but I have a 20 year old site with over 100 pages, and I'll bet switching is a bigger deal than just throwing a switch on my CPANEL. Yes, I realize I may have to eventually switch, but I really need need help now. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: "fails with multiple problems when it is wrongly linked as https" - what happens exactly? Do you have a SSL cert installed?

Comment: @MrWhite  No... I don't have an SSL certificate. I don't even know how they work. The site has always been just HTTP. So when the browser goes there ewith an https link, the  problems are too many to list. Cookie writes/reads fail, <IMG tags> can't fetch graphics, literally half the site won't work. Since ecause the page is NOT secure, and the URL is saying it IS, the console shows that the page is denied permission to do anything. So either I have to find a way to force the browser to re-direct, or I might as well shut down the site. Shame! Site worked fine for 20 years!

Answer (score 1):

To redirect your website from HTTPS to HTTP, add the following rule in your website’s .htaccess file:

```
# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'll give it a try in about 5 minutes... thanks.. I'm on a chat with my hosting support at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to do anything. I can tell because on loading any page, my JavaScript (see my OP) detects that it is https, attempts to reload, and this loop. I also tried this, at the suggestion of the hosting company tech support...

# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


--- that doesn't work either. In fact it causes the browser to complain

Comment: This assumes the OP is behind an SSL proxy. There is nothing in the question that suggests this?

Comment: As mentioned in my edite, something LIKE this was part of the solution offered by tech support (so I'll give it a +1). But without the uppermost line (see my last edit), it basically just created an endless loop. And that endless loop pretty much made a mess of my browsers, as they now "remembered" my site was casing loops, and not even trying anymore. Clearing CACHE or cookies didn't help.. it was the browser history (multiple browsers) as noted in my final edit that finally got me back on track.

Answer (score 1):

> No... I don't have an SSL certificate.

You need an SSL cert. If you don't have an SSL cert installed that covers the requested hostname then either:

- The server simply fails to connect as it's not listening on port 443. (Although this doesn't seem to be the case.)

OR,

- There is an SSL cert installed on the server and the server is responding on port 443, but the cert is for a different domain/hostname so the *browser* issues warnings when attempting to connect. The user "should" not accept this cert, in which case they never reach your site.

> Is seems that all browsers now have the following behavior: If you link a site vai https://, any attempts to load it via http://, even explicitly typing that on the browser URL line, will fail. the browser will continually change it to https:

That's not true, unless...

- You have previously implemented an HTTP to HTTPS 301 redirect and you are seeing a cached response/redirect.

OR,

- You have previously implemented [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). In which case the browser (after initially visiting HTTPS) will *always* request HTTPS. This is not reversible, until the `max-age` time expires after the user has visited your "HTTPS" site. But HSTS is quite a deliberate action - this really shouldn't be something that can be implemented "accidentally". (I would also be surprised that the browser would honour the HSTS header if the SLL cert wasn't entirely valid?!)

  Look for a `Strict-Transport-Security` HTTP response header when accessing your site over HTTPS. This indicates that HSTS has been "implemented" on your site.

---

**UPDATE:**

> 1. In my main (document root level), the tech support added these lines....
>
>    ```
>    Header always unset Strict-Transport-Security
>    RewriteEngine On
>    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
>    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
>    ```

If you are having to explicitly `unset` the STS header then it suggests "something else" is already setting it!? This header is not set by default, so it would be a good idea to find out where/what is setting it in the first place. (The web host themselves should never set a header like this.)

*Aside:* Minor optimisation by changing `(.*)` (the `RewriteRule` *pattern*) with just `^`. Since you don't need to match or capture the URL-path, it just needs to be successful (since you are using `REQUEST_URI`) in the *substitution* string.

> 2. But why were MY browsers "insisting" on HTTPS? ... But oddly, IE and Edge did work, which led me to realize the difference... I don't
>    use those browsers often (except to check compatibility), so the
>    difference was this: Despite suggestions of clearing cache and
>    cookies, apparently none of those options really flush the history.
>    And if an HTTPS was in recent history, the browsers seem to
>    automatically revert to that one. .... Once history was truly cleared,
>    there was no longer a problem.

Browser "history" itself would not cause this problem, except that the browser address bar will tend to (sometimes *annoyingly*) auto-complete to URLs recently visited. But this wouldn't cause a redirect-loop.

So, from this, is the conclusion that it was an HSTS issue? Did your domain appear in the `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` list for HSTS-enabled domains? However, this won't solve the problem for any other users who have recently visited your site over HTTPS. They will still be forced to HTTPS until the period determined by the `max-age` argument from when they last visited passes.

To clarify:

- Your site works perfectly OK for me... redirects back to HTTP.
- You do already have valid SSL certs installed for both your main domain and subdomain! If you didn't then you would see a browser warning before reaching your site over HTTPS and the browser would fail to connect (no redirect would occur) - as mentioned above.
- You have quite a few HTTPS URLs indexed in Google. Google will tend to favour HTTPS over HTTP if it is available. A JavaScript "redirect" as you were doing initially wouldn't necessarily dissuade Google. Incidentally, the JS redirect only redirects the main page on which the script runs. Any static resources (images, JS, CSS, etc) that are requested over HTTPS would not be redirected. A JS-redirect is not strictly a redirect - to the user-agent/search engine it's just another 200 OK response, not a 3xx response.

Comment: You've always been very helpful to me, so i appreciate your help this time. I know this is no longer a cache redirect response, because I've done everything possible to clear cache, clear history, and clear cookies. The fact that this behavior persists even on older browser versions on an old Win-XP machine makes me leery of this being a browser rule (despite seeing the commentary I quoted). I have NOT previously implemented " HTTP to HTTPS 301 redirecting". I have not previously implemented  HSTS, Why would I with an HTTP site? But i have asked my hosting company if THEY intentionally did so.

Comment: Also, I have no clue how to 'look" for an "STS header. It really sucks that my hosting company (A2 Hosting) would suddenly pull the rug out from under me. Sadly, 1st level tech support has already tried some re-directs in my HTACCESS file, that don't work any better than mine. This is a real headache. I guess I'll just have to pay for an SSL certificate, whatever that does. Fortunately 99% of my in-site links and reference are all relative paths, so switching should be less than a weeks work. But still, the host company really screwed me here.

Comment: "on an old Win-XP machine" - this is unlikely to be an HSTS issue then. "pay for an SSL certificate" - SSL certs are often available free these days with services like "Let's Encrypt". Do you mind sharing the domain so I can check?

Comment: I think I've made some progress, as I'll explain in my edit. The site is under heavy reconstruction, but the main landing page is actually in a subdomain: http://peterpan.pixyland.org . And YES... i will at some point go to SSL. Fortunately, as I've always coded site links as relative to my own document root, it will be less painful than it might have been. I just don't like being forced to switch.

Comment: Your site works ok for me. Incidentally, you do appear to already have valid SSL certs for both your main domain and subdomain. So, is the conclusion that it was an HSTS issue in the browser? Did your domain appear in the list of HSTS enabled domains in Google Chrome? I've updated my answer with regards to your question update.

Comment: Thanks Mr White! Tech support at my hosting company added two things... first a line to UNSET HSTS, and second a couple of lines like the ones I already tried in my HTACCESS file. That way, as you suggest, i don't have to worry about putting a javascript in every file. I also had to flush my browser history (not as easy as flushing cache or cookies!), because my browser had alread 'remeberd" that i had too many redirects, so it wouldn't even try anymore.

Comment: Also, My hosting company does appear to have some kind of blanket SSl cert, but the trouble is my site is just currently not ready. When i first removed my own javascripst to redirect, i saw right away that dozens of failed fetches of graphics were happening. Console would say 'attempt to access secure content in an insecure way" I'm sure I could hunt down and fix all the problems. I already code 90% of my in site links as relative, but there are a lot of "escapees". So for now the panic is over, Thanks for the help. Eventually I'll go HTTPS, but now i can do it when I'm prepared! Thanks man!

Comment: Also, you mentioned that HSTS doesn't happen "accidentally" I always like to consider the last thing I did. After all, in the past I mentioned that my javascripts were already correcting all those nice google references. So what happened? Well I moved my sites from hostmonster to A2 hosting. Actually they did the whole move for me, and not surprisingly there were a lot of problems I later discovered which were, as you say, not 'accidental". So this is just the latest malady. HSTS is now UNSET for my domain, but must be being set at a lower level (maybe the root level htaccess!)).